# Update table from 2 Selects from a different database with thousands of rows SQL

Tags: sql-server

I have 2 Openquerys that are just simple selects from 2 tables. My objective is to populate a single table with data from those 2 queries that basically return the same thing but with different names.

Example

1st Warehouse 1

```
Select * From OpenQuery ('SELECT * FROM Warehouse1')
```

2nd Warehouse 2

```
Select * From OpenQuery ('SELECT * FROM Warehouse2')
```

There are thousands of rows that i need to update my SQL table. Problem is, this is very expensive if i use UNION, and my question is how can achieve this for best performance possible? Also this is data from an external database so i really can't change the queries

I have to update my main table with these queries only when user access the list that shows the data

**EDIT.**

I wasn't very clear but both tables return same type of column

```
| ID  |  Warehouse | Ticket | Item | Qty
```

One belongs to Warehouse 1, the other to Warehouse 2, both have different amount of rows.

Comment: 'return the same thing but with different names' - what does this mean I wonder.

Comment: sorry, edited the post to explain

Answer (score 0):

You can use inner join with update for this you need to make table alias as shown below

```
UPDATE A    
  SET A.<ColName> = B.<ColName>
from Warehouse1 A
  INNER JOIN Warehouse2 B
    ON A.<Id> = B.<Id>
--where if required
```

Comment: How does this work? there is nothing connecting both tables, how can i join them? Their ID rows have different data

Comment: Two update table based on another table you need some unique record that might be Id, Ticket, Item or something other in your case.

Answer (score 0):

But why you need to UNION?
You can simply insert 2 times under a transaction.

```
BEGIN TRY
BEGIN TRAN T1
   INSERT into mytable 
       --select from openquery table 1
   INSERT into mytable
       --select from openquery table 2
COMMIT TRAN T1
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
   ---handle error
   ROLLBACK TRAN T1
END CATCH
```

Comment: pls try and correct me if i am wrong. Union will do a memory manipulation which will take time.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone with the same problem as me. Here is the solution i came up with that suits my problem better.

I save the open query on a view since I don't need to change anything or insert in my database at all

```
/*************************** Views ********************************/
GO
IF OBJECT_ID('viewx_POE', 'v') IS NOT NULL
DROP VIEW viewx_POE
GO
CREATE VIEW viewx_POE AS 
SELECT ET0104 AS Armazem, 
       ET0109 AS Localizacao, 
       ET0102 AS Etiqueta,
       ET0101 AS Artigo,
       ET0103 AS Quantidade    
FROM OpenQuery(MACPAC, 'SELECT FET001.ET0104, FET001.ET0109, FET001.ET0102, FET001.ET0101, FET001.ET0103
FROM AUTO.D805DATPOR.FET001 FET001
WHERE (FET001.ET0104=''POE'') AND (FET001.ET0105=''DIS'')');
/**************************************************************************/
GO
IF OBJECT_ID('viewx_CORRICA', 'v') IS NOT NULL
DROP VIEW viewx_CORRICA
GO
CREATE VIEW viewx_CORRICA AS
SELECT GHZORI AS Armazem,
       GHNEMP AS Localizacao,
       LBLBNB AS Etiqueta,
       GHLIB5 AS Artigo,           
       LBQTYD AS Quantidade 
FROM OpenQuery(MACPAC, 'SELECT GA160H.LBLBNB, GA160H.GHLIB5, GA160H.GHZORI, GA160H.GHNEMP, GA160M.LBQTYD
FROM D805DATPOR.GA160H GA160H, D805DATPOR.GA160M GA160M
WHERE GA160M.LBLBNB = GA160H.LBLBNB AND (GA160H.GHZORI=''CORRICA'' AND GA160H.GHCSTA=''DIS'')');
```

And then when needed I select the view depending on the user rank and return whatever i need from it

```
GO
IF OBJECT_ID('dbo.spx_SELECT_RandomLocalizacoes') IS NOT NULL
DROP PROCEDURE spx_SELECT_RandomLocalizacoes
GO
CREATE PROCEDURE spx_SELECT_RandomLocalizacoes
    @LocalizacoesMax int,   
    @Armazem int
AS
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON  

DECLARE @Output int




IF ( @Armazem = 'POE' )
    BEGIN
        SELECT TOP(10) xa.IdArmazem, vpoe.Localizacao, vpoe.Etiqueta, vpoe.Artigo, vpoe.Quantidade 
        FROM viewx_POE vpoe
        INNER JOIN xArmazem xa 
        ON vpoe.Armazem = xa.Armazem
        ORDER BY NEWID()
    END
    ELSE IF ( @Armazem = 'CORRICA' )
    BEGIN
        SELECT TOP(@LocalizacoesMax) * FROM viewx_CORRICA ORDER BY NEWID()
    END

END
```